# Unable to attach a excel file which created from pandas dataframe in email from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mime-types, email-attachments

I am reading an file from amazon S3 and then doing some data manulipations in pandas and then sending  an automoated email . The filename is always is going renamin the same .

I am trying to convert the `dataframe`modelput to xls file and attach it in the email

How to fix this

**My code**

```
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
from email import encoders
import base64


role = get_execution_role()
bucket='cotydata'
input_date='20190411'
data_key = 'modeloutput'+'.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
output_key='UI_'+input_date
output_bucket='model-output-ui'
# Insert weather api key here 
api_key= 'key'
#read modeloutput and prepare dataframe
modeloutput = pd.read_csv(data_location)
modeloutput['Lane_Score'] = modeloutput['FLAG']=='Y'
modeloutput['Lane_Score']modeloutput.groupby(['ORG','DSTN']).Lane_Score.transform('mean')
df = modeloutput.to_excel("Outpout.xls")

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = "456621"
msg['From'] = "jmie@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "rahul@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Dialy Report"
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')    

filename = df

# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
fo = open(filename, "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64

# Define the attachment section
part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, encodedcontent)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg)
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: to_excel doesn't return a file name.
I don't know what debugging methods you have used, but I would recommend stepping through the code with a debugger, line-by-line, and checking if all your variables always have the right values assigned.

Comment: @sneep, I am able to send the email without attachment . With attachment is failing. I am missing something

Comment: `filename = df` is incorrect imo. If the file name is not going to change use `filename = "Outpout.xlsx" missing the x in above code. Make sure to provide the path in open. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770471/how-attach-pandas-dataframe-as-excel-in-email-triggered-from-python/55772451#55772451

Comment: @Sid, Still not working.

Comment: @Rahulrajan did you look at the other answer? Also you are never creating the `xlsx` file. Change `df = modeloutput.to_excel("Outpout.xls")` to `modeloutput.to_excel("Outpout.xlsx")`

Comment: @Sid, getting an SMTPAuthenticationError: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6') error now

Comment: @Rahulrajan please post another question. Not sure why that error would come up if you were able to login earlier.